# $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_1, \tau_2$ be topologies in the same set $X$, where $\beta_1$ is a basis for $\tau_1$ and $\beta_2$ is a basis for $\tau_2$.

$\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ iff for all $B$ in $\beta_1$ and for all $x$ in $B$, exists $A$ in $\beta_2$ such that $x \in A \subseteq B$.

My attempt:

Let $B \in \beta_1$ and $x \in B$. Then $B \in \tau_1$ and off course, $B \in \tau_2$. By hypothesis, $\beta_2$ is a basis for $\tau_2$ then $\exists A \in \beta_2: x \in A \subseteq B$.

Now, my problem is for the other way, I have been unsuccessfully trying. A classmate told me that, with those hypothesis, we can prove that $\beta_1 \subseteq \beta_2$; and I understand that once I proved that, then $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ (I already proved that statement), but I have no clue how to start.

I would really appreciate if you can help me to understand that statement of my classmate, or  provide me another hint to solve this exercise.

Comment: @Ulli Given their notation elsewhere, the appropriate set inclusion notation should probably be $\subseteq$.

Comment: @Jhon C In case it is not clear, the idea is that a topology $\tau$ is the set of open sets, i.e., we view $\tau$ as a subset of the power set. On the other hand, $\preceq$ is ambiguous; it could refer to any one of many possible partial orderings.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was misleading, indeed. Since you use $\subseteq$ elsewhere, of course you should use it for the topologies as well. Thank you, @destine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, every $\tau_{1}$-open set $U$ is a union of elements in $\beta_{1}$, by definition of *basis*.

**Second**, the hypothesis implies every basis element $B \in \beta_{1}$ is a union of basis elements in $\beta_{2}$. To see this, choose for each point $x \in B$ a basis element $B_{x} \in \beta_{2}$ such that $x \in B_{x} \subseteq B$, as the hypothesis guarantees we are able. Then
$$ B = \bigcup_{x \in B} \{x\} = \bigcup_{x \in B} B_{x}. $$
That is, $B$ is $\tau_{2}$-open.

Since $U$ is thereby a union of $\tau_{2}$-open sets, we conclude $U$ itself is $\tau_{2}$-open. This proves $\tau_{1}$ is at least as coarse as $\tau_{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

> A classmate told me that, with those hypothesis, we can prove that $\beta_1\subset \beta_2$

This claim is false.

Consider $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\text{std}}) $ and $(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{\text{dis}}) $

$$\tau_{\text{std}} \subset\tau_{\text{dis}} $$

$\beta_{\text{std}}=\{(a,b): a, b\in\Bbb{R},a<b\}$

$\beta_{\text{dis}}=\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb{R}\}$

$$\beta_{\text{std}} \not \subset \beta_{\text{dis}}$$

---

Hint (for original claim) :

$U\in \tau \iff \forall a\in U, \exists B\in\beta $ such that $a\in B\subset \beta$